# Autocomplete that is working with multiple textbox with the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am making an autocomplete function. When I type the ID of the user. The other textbox should fetched the name. For example, `

> I typed "4" then the other textbox should have the value of
> "hwoarang".

My current function is working for first textbox only. It is not dynamic. Is there a way where i  can do it dynamically? I think i need to autoincrement my ID in controller because in Ajax i'm just calling the ID which is only good for 1 textbox.

| userid | user | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hwoarang | 4 |
| 2 | paul | 5 |

Ajax:

```
                $(document).ready(function(){


                    var list =$('#list').DataTable({  // This is for fetching my data
      dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'print', 'csv', 'copy', 'excel', 'pdfHtml5'
        ],columnDefs: [ {
targets: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
className: 'bolded'
}
],

        "processing": false, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.    
        "order": [], //Initial no order.
        "paging":false,
        
 
        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
              "url": "<?php echo site_url('controller/lists')?>",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function ( data ) {
                
        
     
            }
    
           
        },

 
    });


               $(document).on('keyup', '#id', function(event){   // This is my autocomplete function
               event.preventDefault();
                   
               var id= $('.id').val();
    
               
                    $.ajax({
                           url:"<?=site_url('controller/autocomplete')?>",
                           method:"GET",
                           data:{id:id},
                           dataType:"json",
                           success:function(data){
                               $('#id').val(data.id); 
                               $('#user').val(data.user);      

                                    
                           }
                           })
                     
               
               });
               
                   });
```

Controller

```
public function lists()
{
    
    
    $list = $this->controller->fetching_function();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    
    foreach ($list as $person1) {
        $no++;
        

        
        
        $row = array();
        $row[] = '<tr><input type="text" style="width:50px; height:20px;"   id="user" name="user" ></td>';
        $row[] = '<tr><input type="text" style="width:50px; height:20px;"   id="id" name="id" ></td>'; // If i type the id "4", then the textbox for name should be "hwoarang"
        $data[] = $row;

    }
    
    $output = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $this->controller->count_all(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->controller->count_filtered(),
        "data" => $data,
    );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}


function autocomplete(){
    $output=array();
    $id=$this->input->get('id');

    
    $data = $this->model->getdetails($id);
    
    
    
    foreach($data as $row){

        $output['id']     = $row->id;
        $output['user']   = $row->user;

    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Model:

```
function getdetails($id){
        
        
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query=$this->db->get('users');
    
    return $query->result();
    
}
```

Comment: You can use class selector instead of id .

Comment: In the ajax portion for the 'keyup' event, aren't you wanting to call the Controller's autocomplete() method because right now you have this url:"<?=site_url('controller/lists')?>". I was thinking it should be url:"<?=site_url('controller/autocomplete')?>

Comment: @Swati but when i use class and applied to the textbox, once i type "4", all textboxes  that has class="autocomplete" are returning "hwoarang". It should be supposed the first row of textboxes only. Just like this:  https://prnt.sc/Xw2EKhCppXrd

Comment: @J2112O oops, thank you for pointing that out. I edited it now. I just have miscopied my testing codes. My bad and thank you.

Comment: @Dark. No worries. Glad I could help in that aspect at least. Good luck with your codes.

Comment: Hi,did you resolve this or still looking for answer ?

Comment: Hello @Swati. Thank you for commenting. This has been solved already. Just got it yesterday after days of hardwork. Thank you